# PostgreSQL script gives wrong output

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Im trying to make a script that will assign a ticket to the agent from specific group and with the lowest amount of tickets. I've already made a loop that can assign ticket to the agent with lowest amount of tickets but when I add the lines where it needs to assign to the specific group the script gives output for only one and the same agent.

This is the output:

- NOTICE:  Agent ID: 2
- NOTICE:  Ticket amount: 3
- NOTICE:  Agent ID: 2
- NOTICE:  Ticket amount: 3
- NOTICE:  Assign the ticket to agent 2
- DO
- Query returned successfully in 506 msec.

```
do $$
declare
    counter int := 1;
    zgloszenia int := 0;
    agenci int;
    agent int :=0;
    o int := 1000;
    x int;
    zgloszenie int;
begin
    select count(usr_id) from vuserssupportgroups into agenci;
    while agenci > counter loop
        select usr_id from vuserssupportgroups where (supportgroupid = '1') order by usr_id limit 1 into agent;
        select count(1) from vincidents where serviceuserid = agent and (statusname = 'Nowy' or statusname = 'Otwarty' or statusname = 'W realizacji')  into zgloszenia; --policzenie incydentów
        select * from incidents where serviceuserid is null and (statusid = '1')  into zgloszenie;
        raise notice 'Agent ID: %', agent; 
        raise notice 'Ilość zgłoszeń: %', zgloszenia;
        if zgloszenia<o then
            o := zgloszenia;
            x := agent;
        end if;
        counter = counter + 1;
    end loop;
    update incidents
    set serviceuserid = x
    where incidentid = zgloszenie and serviceuserid is null and supportgroupid = '1';
    raise notice 'Przypisz zgłoszenie do agenta %', x;
end
$$;
```

Comment: Hi there. Please add a data sample and the expected results, so that we can try your script. cheers

Comment: @JimJones Here you can download the database https://www97.zippyshare.com/v/fS5oYijp/file.html
The result should be that the output is the agent from specified group with lowest amount of tickets. Hope you understand

Comment: Cześć Paweł. You should put the data in a fiddle. e.g https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30 There you add create table and insert statements, so that we can better reproduce your environment. Downloads from external links are discouraged in SO.

Comment: It's not possible for me to do that. I hoped that someone can look at the script and tell me that some variable or line should be different. It's a simple loop so I think there is no need to reproduce enviroment. It spits out the same value for agent when loop goes so there must be something wrong and Im not able to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote nice race condition. When you use UPDATE based on some selected data, then you should to use [`FOR UPDATE`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/transaction-anomalies-with-select-for-update/) clause ever (you don't need it if you use isolation level [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html), but this can have some performance or operations impacts)